# What does ' : ' do in a java loop?

Tags: java, loops

```
public int wordsCount(String[] words, int len) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (String s : words) {
    if (s.length()==len) {
    counter++;
    } 
    
  }
  return counter;
  
}
```

Here I am trying to find the number of strings and the length of the inputs given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon does nothing, aside from allowing your code to compile!

`:` is just part of the syntax of the [*enhanced for statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), also less-formally known as the ["for each loop"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html).

As it says in the "for each loop" link above:

> ```
> void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
>     for (TimerTask t : c)
>         t.cancel();
> }
> ```
>
> When you see the colon (`:`) read it as "in." The loop above reads as "for each TimerTask t in c."

So, applying the same interpretation to your code, read it as "for each String s in words".

Answer (score 0):

The loop you have used is the `for each loop` inside your function `wordsCount`.

What the `for each loop` does is, traverse the whole array based on the underlying data type of the array.So you don't have to create a loop counter to traverse, rather, as in your case `String s` will be used to traverse the String array where `s` is your current element in the array.

The syntax: `for ([Data type][variable] : [source array/iterable])`